# VBA - filling empty cell with 0

Tags: vba, excel

How to fill empty cells with 0 in one column?
I suppose my code is complete but it's not working.

```
Sub test()

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("B2307:B10000")
If Len(cell.Value) = 0 Then
    cell.Value = 0
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: @pnuts well, you know, sometimes you want to automate stuff...

Answer (score 6):

if you really need vba for this, here is a better way

```
Sub test()

    On Error Resume Next
    Range("B2307:B10000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) = 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub test()

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("B2307:B10000")
If Trim(cell.Value) = "" Then
    cell.Value = 0
End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: I do not think this inferior (from performance point of view) solution deserves up-votes. Btw. IsEmpty(cell.Value) is also a nice and useful function. :)

Comment: Yeah I know but I just wanted to make the least amount of changes in the code of the OP I am lazy :p

Answer (score 2):

Without VBA:

```
Goto Special, Blanks
type '0'
Ctrl+Enter
```

With VBA:

```
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "0"
```

Comment: The question was about VBA.

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile: I added a VBA solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("B2307:B10000").Cells
        If Len(cell.Value) = 0 Then
            cell.Value = "0"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that the solution by Rosetta is the most elegant one for this very special case (empty cells), I think the following is the most general because you can easily adjust it to more situations by changing the formula.

```
set rng = Range("B2307:B10000")
rng.Formula = Application.Evaluate("=IF(ISBLANK(" & rng.Address & "),0," & rng.Address & ")")
```

Remember this pattern, this is so useful!